# Deploy node code without restart

Tags: node.js

According to Uber it's possible to deploy code to node without restart. Where can I read more about this? I expecting it's not forever or pm2.

> That’s where the second strength Uber found in Node.js (quick iteration) comes into play:
>   through an interactive testing environment called REPL - Read Eval Print Loop - JavaScript allows
>   developers to deploy new code - and fix the errors that new code may create - without having to
>   stop any processes.
>   “One of the things that makes Node.js uniquely suited to running in production is that you can
>   inspect and change a program without restarting it,” said Ranney. “So very few other languages
>   offer that capability. Not a lot of people seem to know that ability exists, but indeed you can
>   inspect and even change your program while it’s running without restarting it.”

Source: https://nodejs.org/static/documents/casestudies/Nodejs-at-Uber.pdf